# Android Calendar RRULE - Events not being created in the calendar

Tags: android, calendar, rrule

I would appreciate any possible help from people that have already experienced the same problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-developers/rrule/android-developers/4di2k6c49XY/EiS5FRqcwxoJ

Thanks.

EDIT:
Problem found: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60589

Comment: It is better on stackoverflow to put the details of your problem in the body of your post, rather than rely on a link, which is inconvenient and may become invalid. (You can edit this into your question.)

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved in new Calendar API implementations.